# Can anyone help me resolve my error for linear regression?

Tags: r, regression

I am currently trying to run a linear regression but I seem to keep running into this problem where I get this returning error when running my code through R :

```
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) :   
NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'
```

In addition: Warning message:

```
In storage.mode(v) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion"
```

I am not sure why I keep getting this error as I do not have any NA or NAN

Here is my entire code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(vtable)
library(sjPlot)
library(readxl)

S1501_Data <- read_excel("~/Desktop/Econ 301 Exercise #2/ACSST5Y2021/S1501-Data.xlsx")
                                                       

S2403_Data <- read_excel("~/Desktop/Econ 301 Exercise #2/ACSST5Y2021-2/S2403-Data.xlsx")
 
Ex2_S2403 <- S2403_Data[ , c(1, 2, 3, 7, 23, 27, 31, 47, 55, 71, 107)]
Ex2_S1501 <- S1501_Data[ , c(1, 2, 31, 35, 39, 43, 47, 51, 55, 59, 235)]

Ex2_1 <- merge(Ex2_S2403, Ex2_S1501, by = c("GEO_ID", "NAME"))

Ex2_2 <- mutate(Ex2_1,
                pct_002 = 100*C01_002E/C01_001E,
                pct_006 = 100*C01_006E/C01_001E,
                pct_007 = 100*C01_007E/C01_001E,
                pct_008 = 100*C01_008E.x/C01_001E,
                pct_012 = 100*C01_012E.x/C01_001E,
                pct_014 = 100*C01_014E.x/C01_001E,
                pct_018 = 100*C01_018E/C01_001E,
                pct_027 = 100*C01_027E/C01_001E)

names(Ex2_2)[names(Ex2_2) == "C01_059E"] <- "MedEarnings"
names(Ex2_2)[names(Ex2_2) == "C01_008E.y"] <- "pct_9_12th"
names(Ex2_2)[names(Ex2_2) == "C01_009E"] <- "pct_HS"
names(Ex2_2)[names(Ex2_2) == "C01_010E"] <- "pct_somecollege"
names(Ex2_2)[names(Ex2_2) == "C01_011E"] <- "pct_AssocDeg"
names(Ex2_2)[names(Ex2_2) == "C01_012E.y"] <- "pct_BachDeg"
names(Ex2_2)[names(Ex2_2) == "C01_013E"] <- "pct_GradDeg"
names(Ex2_2)[names(Ex2_2) == "C01_014E.y"] <- "pct_HSorHigher"
names(Ex2_2)[names(Ex2_2) == "C01_015E"] <- "pct_BachorHigher"

sumtable(Ex2_2)

regA <- lm(MedEarnings ~ pct_BachorHigher , data = Ex2_2)
tab_model(regA)
regB <- lm(MedEarnings ~ pct_008 , data = Ex2_2)
tab_model(regB)
regC <- lm(MedEarnings ~ pct_9_12th + pct_HS + pct_BachDeg + pct_GradDeg, data = Ex2_2)
tab_model(regC)
regD <- lm(MedEarnings ~ pct_002 + pct_006 + pct_008 + pct_012 + pct_014 + pct_018, data = Ex2_2)
tab_model(regD)
regE <- lm(MedEarnings ~ pct_006 + pct_008 + pct_018 + pct_9_12th + pct_somecollege + pct_BachorHigher, data = Ex2_2)
tab_model(regE)
```

If anyone could help me figure out why I keep getting this error message that would be great!

I have tried asking if there were any NA or NAN in my code and it came back as false.

Comment: Check your data. The error is telling you that you are doing something to the `MedEarnings` variable that results in `NA` or a non-finite value in your outcome variable.

Comment: are you dividing by zero anywhere in the mutate steps and introducing `Inf` into your dataset? not possible to know why you're getting that error without the full `S1501_Data' and `S2403_Data` data  sets.